# PHP and arrays, trying to echo answers

Tags: php, html

So what I am trying to do is put this questionnaire at the lower part of my home page, so people may click the checkbox corresponding to what school they are in. Once they check it, I would like them to submit it, and when it submits, takes them back to the same page, but with "echo " you go to....";

For some reason when I have this code in the document, the page won't even load. However if I take that part off, the page loads, the check boxes are there, but it's not doing what I'd like. I will list the entire Page code below, hopefully is an easy fix. I just want once they choose, to echo what they choose.

Thanks in advance!

```
<? php 
$school = $_POST["school"]; 
$school_count = count( $school ); 
print( “You attend $school : “ ); 
foreach($school as $school) { 
 print("$school, "); 
}

?>
```

Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Personal Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Header used in all pages -->
    <?php include 'header.php' ?>
        <div class="body">
        <h2><u>My Personal  Website...About ME!</u></h2>
            <!-- Picture, nicely aligned -->
                <img id="picture" src="../images/richard.jpg" alt="richard">
<!--Summary of what my website is about -->
        <p id="summary">Here is a little about myself....</p>
        <p>My name is Terrence Horan, I love in Montour Falls, NY, not to far from Ithaca, NY. I attend Cornell University and am majoring in Information Science, and hopefully will get a minor in Computer Science. I love anything that involves technology,however if you would like to read more, dont be shy! Come in a browse my website!</p>
       </div>

<!--Questionaire near the bottom of the page -->
        <div id="schoolform">
<form action=“myaction.php” method=“post”> 
What school are you enrolled in at Cornell?
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "CE" />College of Engineering 
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "CAS" /> College of Arts and Sciences 
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "CAAP" />College of Architecture, Arts, and Planning.
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= “CALS" />College of Agriculture and Life Sciences 
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "ILR" />School of Industrial and Labor Relations (ILR) 
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "CHE" />College of Human Ecology 
 <input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value= "Hotel" />School of Hotel Administration
</form>
</div>


<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
<!--Footer.php used in all my pages -->
       <?php include 'footer.php' ?>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things;

1. In your foreach, you're overwriting your original $school variable. So you're always limited to only 1 school (max).
2. You should check if the form has been submitted before showing the result (otherwise you're basically getting errors.

I would rather write it like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['school']) && is_array($_POST['school']) && count($_POST['school']) > 0) {
   echo 'You attend the following schools: ', implode(', ', $_POST['school']);
} else {
   echo 'no schools selected yet.';
}
?>
```

Comment: i went ahead and replaced mine with yours, tho even when I check a box, it still says no schools selected yet.

Comment: Try replacing the code with a <?php var_dump($_POST);?> then check the checkboxes, and use the submit button. This should show if the myaction.php page actually even gets the post data in the first place. As well as its exact form.

Comment: i updated the code in the OP, that is how i have it now. Now it just says array(0) {} at the bottom instead of no schools selected.

Comment: That means that for some reason the PHP script never actually gets the result from the form. Strange... At least now you know your PHP code was not the reason it didn't work.

Comment: On a sidenote; how exactly do you submit the form? I'm not seeing any submit buttons in there?

Comment: I had it, just didnt post it. When I had the first thing you posted in my code, and click submit, it directs me to an error page "The requested URL /other/php/â€œmyaction.phpâ€ was not found on this server.". where should i go now? I didnt really want it to xfer me to another page, and when i tried action="" it still sent me to the error page. I just wanted it to say instead of no schools selected, to say, "you attend..."

Comment: Your HTML contains <form action=“myaction.php” method=“post”> . Notice that those quotes are different from the ones in the rest of the page. They should be normal, standard, quotes. So <form action="myaction.php" method="post"> instead.

You could also just link to the page you're at at that point in time instead.

Comment: one more thing, any idea why this is giving me undefined index action error? <?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>

Comment: Because $_REQUEST['action'] does not exist. The script never gets it. Which in turn means your form does not have a field with name="action"

Comment: so should i delete the thing or?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your php:

1) `<? php` needs to be `<?php`.

2) You seem to be using a special character to declare a string here:

```
print( “You attend $school : “ );
```

Instead, it should be:

```
print( "You attend $school : " );
```

3) You can not use the same variable as the array with `foreach` because an *invalid argument* will be supplied when it repeats the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

A few little improvements on your code may help you.

```
// initialize variables
$school = false;
$school_count = false;

// check if you are getting something from $_POST
if ( isset( $_POST["school"] ) !== false ) {
    $school = $_POST["school"];
}

// work only if there is something to do
if ( $school !== false ) {
    $school_count = count( $school );
    print( "You attend ".$school." : " );
    foreach( $school as $values ) { // don't use the same variable name
        print( $values.", ");
    }
}
```

Obviously you still should have the right kind of data on each step.

Comment: Technically, this is still not valid php because the string is being declared with a special character: `“`

Comment: I don't see any error, neither xdebug, but if you prefer $variable.'string', that's easy to change. The above is just a quick transformation, valid and correct

Comment: It's not that.  The problem is with the character infront of You: `“You`.  That character is not a possible way to start a string.

Answer (score -1):

There is error in your foreach loop change it as`foreach(school as somothervariable){echo 'anything';}` currently you are using same variable school.

Comment: Php variables require a `$` infront of them: `$school`.